Ranking de usuarios en una tabla
Es una consulta simple pero soy nuevo en SQL.
Tengo una tabla en la que se registran transacciones, registros de consumos; la misma posee usuario y diferentes datos que no  me importan demasiado para esta consulta.
Es algo asi:



usuariotr
trx




USR01
ABC5487


USR02
SDC4578


USR51
QAZ5477


USR51
QWW2222


USR51
RRR555



Logro hacer que me muestre cada usuario y las cantidad de transacciones que ha registrado.
Con la siguiente consulta

select usuariotr as usuario, count(usuariotr) as cantidad
from PROD.transac group by usuariotr order by count(usuariotr) desc




USUARIO
CANTIDAD




USR01
1


USR02
1


USR51
3



Sería como una especie de ranking, de los usuarios que mas entradas tienen en la tabla.
Ahora bien los usuarios no son descriptivos por lo cual quisiera poder obtener sus descripciones de otra tabla y no logro hacerlo.
La tabla con los nombre de usuario es asi:



usuacodusu
usuanombre




USR01
JUAN LOPEZ


USR02
ESTEBAN SOL


USR51
MARIA NANA



Intenté esto:

select TRANS.usuariotr, USRS.usuanombre from PROD.transac TRANS ,
PROD.usuarios USRS where TRANS.usuariotr = USRS.usuacodusu

PERO NO FUNCIONA.. AYUDA!!

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! un par de cosas.. usa id numericos.. no es necesario agregar la palabra usr al id.. no lo vas a usar para nada mas que relacionar.. luego, lo que queres se puede resolver de varias maneras en sql, pero ya que estas aprendiendo y vas por buen camino, estas buscando hacer un inner join... tambien se puede hacer con subquerys, y hasta con otra query que envuelva esta.. pero anda por inner join.

Como ya te dijeron te toca hacer JOINs entre tablas
Y sería algo básico y sencillo como esto.
Tabla user



id
nombre




1
Juan


2
Pedro


3
Maria



Tabla trans



id
user_id
trans




1
2
compra


2
2
venta


3
3
venta



Query
SELECT t.id, u.nombre, t.trans
FROM user u -- alias de la tabla user
-- Acá estableces la relación entre tablas con su "Dato Común"
INNER JOIN trans t ON t.user_id = u.id

Resultado



id
nombre
trans




1
Pedro
compra


2
Pedro
venta


3
Maria
venta



En imágenes es algo como



[editado]
Para ver el contador sería
SELECT u.nombre, COUNT(t.trans) AS trans
FROM user u -- alias de la tabla user
-- Acá estableces la relación entre tablas con su "Dato Común"
INNER JOIN trans t ON t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.nombre

Resultado



nombre
trans




Pedro
2


Maria
1




Entiendo que buscas algo como esto:
SELECT USRS.usuanombre,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TRANS.trx)  as 'Cantidad'
       FROMPROD.transac TRANS
       INNER JOIN PROD.usuarios USRS 
             ON TRANS.usuariotr = USRS.usuacodusu
       GROUP BY USRS.usuanombre

La sentencia es similar a la que intentaste, solo que no empleamos el join implícito sino el explícito, mediante el INNER JOIN y la clausula ON, esto se considera buena práctica, por lo que deberías evitar el uso del join sin el ON. Por otro lado aplicamos un agrupamiento por el nombre del usuario y contamos la cantidad de TRANS.trx distintas del grupo, entendiendo que trx sería el id de la transacción, posiblemente en tu caso sea igual hacer un COUNT(TRANS.trx) o directamente un COUNT(*), pero desconozco que datos hay en TRANS.

Finalmente lo solucioné asi:
SELECT USRS.USUANOMBRE,
    COUNT(BONOS.AUCOSBUSU)
    FROM PROD.AUCOSBCO BONOS
    INNER JOIN USUARIOS USRS
        ON (UPPER(USRS.USUACODUSU) = UPPER(BONOS.AUCOSBUSU))
    GROUP BY USRS.USUANOMBRE ORDER BY 2 DESC


Fabricio, es lo que yo te puse, es obvio que no iba hacer tu query, pero te puse exactamente la misma estructura para que llegaras a lo que esperabas. Deberías considerar marcar como aceptada mi respuesta ya que creo que además de  resolver tu problema, te ayudé a entender como se hacen las cosas...
